# Barcode not display in Print Preview - javascript print method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, barcode

I want to generate a order receipt with barcode but barcode is not showing in print preview its showing on html page.
Its  working fine on my local server. But on live server its not working.

For printing purpose I have use Javascript method. For barcode using font **B39MHR.TTF**

Javascript Code ==>

```
var divToPrint = document.getElementById("manifest");
newWin = window.open("");
newWin.document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/style.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"print\"/>");
newWin.document.write('<style type="text/css">  @font-face {font-family: \'B39MHR\';src: url(\'font/B39MHR.TTF\');} .barcodefnt {font-family: B39MHR; font-size: 19px;text-align: center;font-family: \'B39MHR\';src: url(\'font/B39MHR.TTF\')}}</style>');
newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
newWin.print();
newWin.close();
```

I will highly appreciate if i can get some help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried the many solution but its not possible with normal javascript. The **JQPrint** plugins is working for me in this issue.

For that have to include only  **[jquery.jqprint-0.3.js](https://github.com/tanathos/jquery.jqprint)** javascript file & single line javascript code as below,

```
$('#sectionID').jqprint(); // sectionID is ID of the section
```